# *** Error in `./mypgm': double free or corruption (out): 0x6f528c38 ***

Tags: c++, linux, raspbian

I am running cpp program in raspberry pi. It is crashing after some time of execution by showing error.
Debug core is giving following message...

```
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
enter code hereUsing host libthread_db library "/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `./mypgm'.
Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
#0  0x76a79f70 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
56  ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt full
#0  0x76a79f70 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
        _sys_result = <optimized out>
        pd = 0x4baff430
        pid = <optimized out>
        selftid = 3853
#1  0x76a7b324 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89
        save_stage = 2
        act = {__sigaction_handler = {sa_handler = 0x0, sa_sigaction = 0x0}, sa_mask = {__val = {
              1995550480, 1994166280, 1994170248, 0, 1991806976, 72, 1972443800, 0, 0, 1993493240, 
              1972528128, 1972445088, 0, 1972531088, 1994166280, 1994170248, 4294967277, 1269817120, 
              1993752896, 1993751604, 1972535816, 1993497000, 0, 1994055744, 4294967277, 1993498228, 
              1972529600, 1269817112, 7, 71, 71, 1269817112}}, sa_flags = 7, sa_restorer = 0x47}
        sigs = {__val = {32, 0 <repeats 31 times>}}
#2  0x76ab5954 in __libc_message (do_abort=<optimized out>, 
    fmt=0x76b6b6e8 "*** Error in `%s': %s: 0x%s ***\n") at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:175
        ap = {__ap = 0x4bafe04c}
        fd = 1
        on_2 = <optimized out>
        list = <optimized out>
        nlist = <optimized out>
        cp = <optimized out>
        written = <optimized out>
#3  0x76abbb80 in malloc_printerr (action=1, str=0x76b6b860 "double free or corruption (out)", 
    ptr=<optimized out>) at malloc.c:4996
        buf = "6f528c38"
        cp = <optimized out>
#4  0x76abcb24 in _int_free (av=<optimized out>, p=<optimized out>, have_lock=0) at malloc.c:3840
        size = <optimized out>
        fb = <optimized out>
        nextchunk = <optimized out>
        nextsize = <optimized out>
        nextinuse = <optimized out>
        prevsize = <optimized out>
        bck = <optimized out>
        fwd = <optimized out>
        errstr = <optimized out>
        locked = <optimized out>
        __func__ = "_int_free"
#5  0x76d259a8 in sqlite3_free () from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libsqlite3.so.0
No symbol table info available.
#6  0x76d5fe04 in ?? () from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libsqlite3.so.0
No symbol table info available.
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

Can any idea how can I fix this....My code running few threads, sqlite3 and gpio libraries for raspberrypi.

Comment: It's impossible for anyone to identify the problem with what you wrote. You should instead use a debugger and try to trace the bug while looking at the code.

Comment: Build a debug version with `-g` and optimisation disabled (`-O0`) and see if you can get that to fail too - that way you'll get a lot more clues.

Comment: It is compiled with -g -O ... "performance debug" option in netbeans.

Comment: Assuming that sqlite3 doesn't free memory twice, the other option of *"double free or corruption (out)"* is that some other code has gone out of bounds and damaged the heap.

Comment: In my code chances are there multiple threads are accessing database...How can I eliminate freeing memory twice.